# Install attribution with expo branch.io SDK and Ad Partner link

Tags: expo, branch.io, attribution

I am trying to test branch.io install attribution from Ad Partner links within branch.io to my Android and iOS apps.

I have followed https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/branch/ to install and configure branch in expo, but now I don't know what to do within my apps to communicate an app install back to branch.io, and I haven't been able to find any assistance elsewhere, even from branch.io.

Additionally, how can I test this functionality without deploying the apps to the app stores?

Answer (score 1):

Expo is not supported currently. If you are on Expo workflow please eject your app as mentioned [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native#install-branch). You'd also need to ensure that the Google Advertising IDs(GAID) can be captured for attribution.

For testing, you can host your APK on your website(TestFight/Firebase for iOS). Deep Linking and attribution will work regardless of the store download location.